# Where does the word 'grognard' come from?

Tags: terminology, history-of-gaming

I see many people online describing themselves as grognards of a particular system or style of play. Usually they're referring to their die-hard love of an out of print version of a game.

But where does the word 'grognard' come from?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grande_Arm%C3%A9e), the name was given by Napoleon to the **Grenadiers à Pied de la Garde Impériale**. "They were the most experienced and brave infantrymen in the Guard, some veterans having served in over 20 campaigns. To join the Grenadiers, a recruit had to have been under the colours for at least 10 years, have received a citation for bravery, be literate and be over 178 cm tall."

Makes sense that it would be applied to crusty gamer misanthropes by the nerds at SPI.

Answer (score 40):

If you check [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grognard), you'll see that it comes from the French, and it has both implications of 'old soldier' and of 'grumbling curmudgeon'.

As for the actual origin, [this thread about the origins of "grognard"](http://www.dragonsfoot.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=43445&view=next) has a link to [an article about its origins](http://web.archive.org/web/20101221065325/https://alanemrich.com/Writing_Archive_pages/grognard.htm) where an explanation is given:

> The term 'grognard,' as applied to
>   veteran wargamers, was first coined
>   back in the early 1970's by John
>   Young. He was, at that time, an
>   employee for [the board] wargame
>   publisher SPI, and the use of the term
>   around the office (and among the local
>   play testers) soon led to 'grognards'
>   being mentioned in one of SPI's
>   magazines (Strategy & Tactics).
>   Several hundred thousand board
>   wargamers picked up the term from that
>   publication and it spread to computer
>   wargamers, as the the board wargamers
>   (the ones with PCs, of course) were
>   the first people to snap up computer
>   wargames when they appeared.